# Django pass multiple words through a URL conf

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Using django, I would like the name of my item through a variable in my URL conf. Say the name of my product is "stack overflow" I would like to be able to go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/stack+overflow/
```

But what I am getting is a "page not found" 404 page. It does work when the name is just word, but not with multiple words.

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^product/(?P<name>\w+)/$', 'crunch.views.product_by_name', name='preview_by_name'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand your regex to match the additional characters that you want to allow in your url.

In your case to allow alphanumeric characters and `+`, this should work:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^product/(?P<name>[\w\+]+)/$', 'crunch.views.product_by_name', name='preview_by_name'),
)
```

Comment: The only issue is that "+" doesn't get automatically decoded to a space character the way I thought it would. So, I am just calling a str.replace("+", " ")

Comment: :) I thought you were trying to use `+` literally. [`urllib.unquote_plus()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote_plus) could be another option for getting the space.